# Как загрузить изображение с сервера в интернете?

Tags: python, requests

Я хочу сделать программу (Python), которая при запуске на определённом сайте скачает картинку (по прямой ссылке, т.е. с .jpg в конце), затем сохранить её на диске. Как мне это сделать?

P.S.
Я пробовал получить запрос с библиотекой requests, конвертировать изображение в байтах с помощью pygame (функция pygame.image.frombuffer(bytes, resolution, format)) и затем сохранить его с помощью pygame.image.save(surface, filename), но постоянно получал ошибку о неверном формате или разрешении, хотя я и скачивал размером 1366x768 и передавал то же самое

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests as rqs

r = rqs.get(url)
file = open(filename, "wb")
file.write(r.content)
file.close()
```

Всё!